# How to scroll divs vertically on next/prev buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

I m creating ticker in which the divs will be scrolling infinitely vertically on next/prev buttons ... I have created it but there is a small issue in it .. when i click on prev button the divs scrolls upward on first click and after that it scrolls downward and same goes for next button as well ..Someone help please

```js
var buttons = $('.next-prev');
$(buttons).each(function(){
$(this).click(function(){
var id = $(this).attr('id');
if(id=="next"){
$('#scroll-div').stop().animate({scrollTop:40},400,'swing',function(){
    $(this).scrollTop(0).find('div:last').after($('div:first', this));
  });
}
else {
$('#scroll-div').stop().animate({scrollTop:40},400,'swing',function(){
   $(this).scrollTop(40).find(' div:first').before($(' div:last', this));
  });
}
})
})
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#scroll-div {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 300px;
    height: 250px;
    background: green;
    padding: 10px;
}

#scroll-div div {
    display: block;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background: cyan;
}

.item:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>

<button class="next-prev" id="next">
up
</button>
<button class="next-prev" id="prev">
down
</button>
</div>

<div id="scroll-div">
    <div>div 1</div>
    <div>div 2</div>
    <div>div 3</div>
    <div>div 4</div>
    <div>div 5</div>
    <div>div 6</div>
    <div>div 7</div>
    <div>div 8</div>
    <div>div 9</div>
    <div>div 10</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var buttons = $('.next-prev');

$('#scroll-div').prepend($('#scroll-div').find('div:last-child')); // prepend last element
$('#scroll-div').scrollTop(40); // scroll div to position 40 so first (div 10) not visible

$(buttons).each(function(){
  $(this).click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    if(id=="next"){
      $('#scroll-div').append($('#scroll-div').find('div:first-child'));   //do modification first     
    } else {
      $('#scroll-div').prepend($('#scroll-div').find('div:last-child')); 
    }
    $('#scroll-div').stop().animate({scrollTop:40},400,'swing'); // then scroll
  })
})
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#scroll-div {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 300px;
    height: 250px;
    background: green;
    padding: 10px;
}

#scroll-div div {
    display: block;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background: cyan;
}

.item:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>

<button class="next-prev" id="next">
up
</button>
<button class="next-prev" id="prev">
down
</button>
</div>

<div id="scroll-div">
    <div>div 1</div>
    <div>div 2</div>
    <div>div 3</div>
    <div>div 4</div>
    <div>div 5</div>
    <div>div 6</div>
    <div>div 7</div>
    <div>div 8</div>
    <div>div 9</div>
    <div>div 10</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you sir .... it is working as expected... but one more thing how to make scroll-div automatically to scroll upward after 3sec but  when hover  on next or prev button the div should stop scrolling by clearInterval i have tried it with your code but there is a issue with it ....